# Serialize an object to encrypted std::fstream (C++)

Tags: c++, std

Is there a way to create an encrypted file stream?

I want to do something like this:

```
string myString;
fstream myStream;

myStream.create("my path", "my password", cipherAlgorithm);
myStream.write(myString); - this code saves my string to an encrypted stream
myStream.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Boost.Asio contains classes and class templates for basic SSL support.

Comment: It would involve a custom class derived from `std::basic_streambuf` that encrypts/decrypts on output/input.

Comment: I would instead suggest a 'sink' (a type of device that you write to) that as it writes encrypts the data. I would then wrap this sink in a boost::stream and then use a boost stream copier to copy the input stream to this output stream. Or you could just use this output stream directly, writing data to it which would then be automatically encrypted (e.g. outStream << myString)

Comment: [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) has encrypted streams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest having a sink object, a type of device that you write to. The sink can be wrapped in a boost stream. The stream can then be written to like any 'standard' output stream

```
#ifndef ENCRYPTION_SINK_HPP__
#define ENCRYPTION_SINK_HPP__

#include <boost/iostreams/categories.hpp>  // sink_tag
#include <iosfwd>                          // streamsize    
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class EncryptionSink
{
  public:
    typedef char                          char_type;
    typedef boost::iostreams::sink_tag    category;

    /**
     * @param underlyingStream where the data is actually written
     * @param key the key to use during encryption 
     * @note we could pass in a path rather than a stream and construct the
     * underlying stream internally. But doing it this way affords the 
     * flexibility of using any ostream type e.g. ofstream, ostringstream, 
     * cout etc.
     */ 
    EncryptionSink(std::ostream &underlyingStream, std::string const &key);

    /**
     * @param buf the data that you write
     * @param n number of bytes to write
     * @return the number of bytes written
     */
    std::streamsize write(char_type const * const buf, std::streamsize const n) const;
    ~EncryptionSink();

    private:
        std::ostream &m_underlyingStream;
        std::string const m_key;
};

#endif // ENCRYPTION_SINK_HPP__
```

The above class takes an underlying stream (or a FILE handle if you prefer) and writes to it in the actual '.cpp' implementation of write using whatever transformations your encryption algorithm requires. For example, the following implementation applies an XOR transformation (I think this is XOR, my knowledge is rusty at best):

```
EncryptionSink::EncryptionSink(std::ostream &underlyingStream, std::string const &key)
    : m_underlyingStream(underlyingStream)
    , m_key(key)
{}

std::streamsize 
EncryptionSink::write(char_type const * const buf, std::streamsize const n) const
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string::size_type t = 0;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < n ; ++i) {
        long result = buf[i] ^ m_key[t];
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << (unsigned char)result;
        m_underlyingStream.write(ss.str().c_str(), 1);
        ++t;
        if(t >= m_key.length()) t = 0;
    }

    return n;

}

// etc.
```

Elsewhere in your code, an instantiation of the sink might be as follows:

```
std::fstream underlyingStream(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
EncryptionSink sink(underlyingStream, std::string("theEncryptionKey"));
boost::iostreams::stream<EncryptionSink> outputStream(sink);
outputStream << "some data!";
outputStream.flush();
```

I imagine you might then need an accompanying DecryptionSink to reverse the operation, using a stream copier to copy the encrypted data back to plain text. Note though that with XOR you wouldn't need to do this since reapplying an 'XOR' will transform back to the original data

EDIT: off the back of this, I have written a simple c++ api demonstrating how such code can be put to more effective use: [cryptex](https://github.com/benhj/cryptex)

Comment: you do not need `std::string("theEncryptionKey")` when creating sink object. `"theEncryptionKey"` is enough

Comment: You're right, but I prefer to not rely on implicit conversions

Comment: Reinventing `std::streambuf`, badly. Streams are wrappers on top of sinks, not beneath them.

Comment: @MSalters -- are you referring to the 'underlyingStream'? Thanks.